# How can I connect points on a 3D scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

So currently, I have all these coordinates and so it's quite easy to create a 3D scatter plot of all the combination of coordinates.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

z = numpy.transpose(z_coords_row)[0:100]
x = numpy.transpose(x_coords_row)[0:100]
y = numpy.transpose(y_coords_row)[0:100]

plt.xticks(numpy.arange(-1.5, 1.5, .25))
plt.yticks(numpy.arange(-1.5, 1.5, .5))

ax.scatter(x, y, z,s=1)
ax.view_init(elev=10., azim=45)
```

This code gives me a result as so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKw1D.png

I've run into lots of problems trying to connect each point with a line to the next point in sequence. How do I go about connecting each point with the next in the array so that it's a smooth line graph?

Comment: I know nothing about 3d charts... but i know this process is called `interpolation`. According to wiki, interpolation is a method of constructing new data points within the range of a discrete set of known data points. Maybe this new keyword will help you.

Comment: From what I've used so far though, the interpolation only works for 1D and only gives more sets of points rather than a line though? Anyone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have enough points using only your coordinates I think what you are looking for is [`plot3D`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot3D). If you need it more smooth line it might be worth looking into [`scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator) which would help generate more points, which you could then insert into `plot3D`.

Example of usage of `plot3D`:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

z_coords_row = numpy.sin(numpy.linspace(0,2*numpy.pi,100))+5
x_coords_row = numpy.sin(numpy.linspace(0,2*numpy.pi,100))
y_coords_row = numpy.cos(numpy.linspace(0,2*numpy.pi,100))

z = numpy.transpose(z_coords_row)[0:100]
x = numpy.transpose(x_coords_row)[0:100]
y = numpy.transpose(y_coords_row)[0:100]

plt.xticks(numpy.arange(-1.5, 1.5, .25))
plt.yticks(numpy.arange(-1.5, 1.5, .5))

ax.scatter(x, y, z,s=5)
ax.plot3D(x,y,z)
ax.view_init(elev=10., azim=45)
```

[image]

Comment: When I try using the ax.plot3D(x,y,z), it gives me the error: 'ValueError: third arg must be a format string'. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: @JesseBatson Could you verify that the type of your `ax` is `matplotlib.axes._subplots.Axes3DSubplot'`?

Comment: It verified that <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.Axes3DSubplot'>

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but I am also using Python 2.7 in case you happen to be using a different version?

Comment: @JesseBatson The code above works on both 3.x and 2.7. Could you try to run the exact piece of code above as a standalone script (adding `plt.show()` at the end) or running it in a jupyter notebook with `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: So I ran yours and it does work! I've found that it's because you have a set equation for your line, whereas I don't have an equation for mine which is why yours works. If I don't have an equation for my path how would I connect the points?