# Connecting points to a central point on 3D scatter Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, line

I'm making a molecular diagram of a tetrahedral molecule where the three outer points(or atoms) need to be connected by lines to the central point.

From [How can I connect points on a 3D scatter plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711843/how-can-i-connect-points-on-a-3d-scatter-plot) I was able to connect the dots, but it produces the incorrect lines.

Here is my code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


x = [1, 2, 1.2, 1.5, 1.5]
y = [1, 1.2, 2, 1.5, 1.5]
z = [.5, .5, .5, 1.2, 2]

a = []
b = []
c = []
for item in x:
    a.append(float(item))
for item in y:
    b.append(float(item))
for item in z:
    c.append(float(item))

r = np.array(a)
s = np.array(b)
t = np.array(c)

ax.set_xlabel("x axis")
ax.set_ylabel("y axis")
ax.set_zlabel("z axis")


ax.scatter(r,s,zs = t, s=200)
ax.plot3D(r,s,z)
plt.show()
```

I'd like all the points to connect to the central point(x=1.5, y=1.5, z=1.2).  Here is what this looks like so far:
 [image: plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `ax.plot3D(r,s,z)` you are plotting a line joining the 5 points one after another. What you need is to plot a line from each point to the point you want.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = [1, 2, 1.2, 1.5, 1.5]
y = [1, 1.2, 2, 1.5, 1.5]
z = [.5, .5, .5, 1.2, 2]
# Change the way you create the array.
# You can do it in several ways.
r = np.array(x, dtype=np.float)
s = np.array([float(i) for i in y])
t = np.array(z) * 1.0

ax.scatter(r,s,zs = t, s=200, label='True Position')

# Iterate over each point, and plot the line.
for x, y, z in zip(r, s, t):
    ax.plot3D([x, 1.5], [y, 1.5], [z, 1.2], 'b')

plt.show()
```

[image: 3d_line_conection_example]